# facebook login not working for react-native app with parse-server hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: react-native, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, facebook-login, parse-server

In my react-native app on android, I get an error when I try to login with facebook using the following call,

```
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(<scope>)
```

This is the error I get,

```
{ 
  code: undefined,
  message: 'unauthorized',
  line: 10800,
  column: 21,
  sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundleplatform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false' 
}
```

I have the initialization code as shown below,

```
Parse.initialize('myapp');
Parse.serverURL = `${serverURL}/parse`;
FacebookSDK.init();
Parse.FacebookUtils.init();
```

I am also setting the `facebookAppIds` as mentioned in the Readme for [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)

The facebook login part works fine, as in the app gets access to the user profile but the user account is not created on the parse-server. I don't know if I need to use any other key for the server.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error by replacing myapp with the application ID on parse-server. But, I am now getting a new error. The call to `Parse.FacebookUtils.login()` does not return. I am able to create new objects and perform other operations on the server.